# Creating Rollover in CSS or Javascript using two images of different sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the Situation.

I am creating a digital gift guide, like a digital ad insert in the Sunday paper.  I am creating a footer that has three gift card type images, that on rollover need to image swap.  The problem is the image the designer has given me for the rollover has some extra height and width due to sparkles she has added to the edges.  She also sent me the rollover image with a 7 degree tilt.  So the dimensions in pixels of the original image are w=156 h=96, and the rollover image is w=206 h=154 (due to tilt and extras added)

I decided to swap images using javascript, but I am fairly new at it, and it may not be right, but it is doing the job.   The problem is the images are swapping, but the new image is shrinking to fit in the space of the original image.  What is the best way to do this simple image swap?

```
<a href="" onMouseOver="document.MyImage.src='img/Free-Gift(Roll).png';" onMouseOut="document.MyImage.src='img/Free-Gift.jpg';">
<img src="img/Free-Gift.jpg" name="MyImage" class="free">

</a> 

.free {
    width: 156px;
    height: 96px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 352px;
}

.freeroll {
    position: absolute;
    width: 206px;
    height: 156px;

}
```

Comment: "...due to sparkles she has added to the edges" D:

Comment: yes, she also happens to be my wife : D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting to set the class:

```
<a href="" onMouseOver="document.MyImage.src='img/Free-Gift(Roll).png';document.MyImage.className='freeroll';" onMouseOut="document.MyImage.src='img/Free-Gift.jpg';document.MyImage.className='free';">
    <img src="img/Free-Gift.jpg" name="MyImage" class="free" />
</a>
```

*However...* there is a better way to do this, using only CSS:

```
<a href="" id="myRollover">Free Gift!</a>

...

#myRollover {
     background-image: url('img/Free-Gift.jpg');
     width: 156px;
     height: 96px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 55px;
     left: 352px;
     text-indent: -9999px;
}

#myRollover:hover {
     background-image: url('img/Free-Gift(Roll).jpg');
     width: 206px;
     height: 156px;
}
```

Comment: You are incredible, this website restores my faith in humanity.

Comment: even you can make an css animation transition (fadding, slide) or use [css sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/)

Comment: I would like to use the CSS provided above but the rollover image shifts down to the right because the box is top left justified.  Is there a way to make it center justified.

Comment: @TheRodStu: Set `margin-top: -(the difference between the heights, divided by two; in this case, 30)px;` and `margin-left: -(the difference between the widths, divided by two; in this case, 25)px;` on the `:hover` and that should fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing rollovers these days is in pure CSS; you should not need to use Javascreeept. Example:

```
<a href="#" class="rollover">&nbsp;</a>

.rollover { 
    width: 156px;
    height: 96px;
    background:url('img/Free-Gift.jpg') no-repeat;
}

.rollover:hover { 
    width: 206px;
    height: 156px;
    background:url('img/Free-Gift(Roll).jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

This excludes all your positioning code BTW. Now theres a number of things you can do from here. For example - instead of using `&nbsp;` you could put words in there to help with accessibility/SEO and set the style to `text-indent` so you cant see the words. Or if you really want an image in there you could nest it and change the css selectors to have the image in there too (`.rollover:hover img`). But please don't use javascript for something as simple as this.